# solid edge add file properties text box to custom menu

Tags: vb.net, solidworks

Is it possible in Solid Edge to add a text field in a custom ribbon that is linked to a file property (such as Document Number or Revision)?  I don't think you can do this within the standard solid edge customization tools, but I'm not sure if it could be done programmatically somehow.  Thanks.

Comment: You are talking about Solid Edge but you used the SolidWorks tag.

Comment: Indeed, that is true.  I don't have enough points to create a new tag, and SolidWorks was the closest available.